# How to create a DataRelation from one column in a table to two columns in another table

Tags: c#, .net

I have a DataTable called `test_results` with the following columns:

1. test_results_id
2. student_id
3. subject
4. score

and a DataTable called `students` with the column:

- student_id

I would like to create a DataRelation between the tables so that I can get all `test_results` rows where

- subject = 'math'
- student_id = x

where x is a student_id from `students`

I want to do this so that I can quickly loop through students and find their math results:

```cs
foreach (DataRow[] student in students){
    DataRow[] mathResults = student.GetChildRows( "relation_student_math_results" );
    foreach (DataRow[] mathResult in mathResults ){
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intitialzing a DataRelation is quite simple; you can use the basic constructor. In your case, something like:

```
DataRelation studentResultsRelation = new DataRelation("StudentResults", students.Columns["student_id"], test_results.Columns["student_id"]);

parentDataSet.Relations.Add(studentResultsRelation);
```

Where parentDataSet is the dataset containing both your datables.

However, this is where it gets a bit tricky. You can't directly query the data relation, as it only defines the relationship between the two tables. What you can do is something like:

1) Find the row that matches the student you want:

```
int studentId = 42;

DataRow[] studentRow = students.Select(String.Format("student_id = {0}"), studentId);
```

2) You can then take advantage of the DataRelation to retrieve all of that students results:

```
//Assumes 1 student row matched your query! Check for 0 rows and more than 1, too!
DataRow[] studentResults = studentRow[0].GetChildRows(studentResultsRelation);
```

You can then loop around these to find the math results:

```
List<DataRow> mathResults = new List<DataRow>();

foreach(DataRow resultRow in studentResults){
  if(Convert.ToString(resultRow["subject"]).Trim().ToUpper() == "MATH")
  {
    mathResults.Add(resultRow);
  } 
}
```

I can see you already had most of this, and I understand what you wanted to do with the data relation; however, I don't believe you can use it directly - instead, you first have to find the rows you want in the child (GetParentRow[s]) or parent table (GetChildRow[s]), and the relation then allows you to quickly find the matching set of rows. You can then filter these as desired.

As an aside, this is a much simpler exercise with a database query.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Using GetChildRows and a data relationship was a lot quicker than a Select query when I tested it with simple join on student_id

Comment: Exploiting the child relationship as in the example above should hopefully be fast enough? If you wanted, you could always store this information as a set of linked lists or even dictionaries keyed by student id. Out of interest, when you mention a select query, do you mean against a database, or against the data tables?

Comment: These tables are a simplification of my actual code and speed is really important. students.Select(String.Format("student_id = {0}"), studentId) was quite a bit slower than using a DataRelation and students.GetChildRows(...). Getting all test results for a student with a relation and then querying this for the 'math' tests is much faster. In OP I was wondering whether this could be done in one relation.